# In AWS EventBridge can I conditionally route events to different targets using the same rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

In AWS EventBridge can I conditionally route events to different targets using the same rule?

Let us say I have three targets. I want to route events to different targets depending on the payload in the `details` field of the event. Is this possible using one rule or do I need different rules for each target?